# How can I uninstall a MSI but not the Bundle itself using WiX MBA?

Tags: wix, installation, burn, wix3.6

**My Requirements:**

I have few MSI files which need to be installed. User can select which one he wants to install/uninstall. For this purpose I have used WiX bootstrapper where I have used WPF UI to list down all the MSI and few buttons to Intstall/Upgrade/Uninstall

Till now I am able to install selected MSI using InstallCondition but could not manage the uninstall. **If I uninstall any of the MSI, the Bundle is also getting uninstalled.** Hence it is not showing in the Add/Remove Program.

So I would like to know if there is any way to allow uninstall of individual MSI but not the Bundle itself?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing your bundle is getting uninstalled because you are using `Engine.Plan(LaunchAction.Uninstall)`. If you use a different action like `Install` or `Modify`, it shouldn't be removed.

To control the install state of the individual MSI packages, I think you can set that in a callback to PlanPackageBegin.

Comment: I was suggesting a way to control the package installation state by changing the package 'InstallContition' value, but I no longer think this is an appropriate practice, so I updated my answer to remove that.