# prevent bundle getting uninstalled until all chained msis are uninstalled

Tags: wix

I use Wix 3.10. I have a custom wix bootstrapper managed installer exe. There are 3 msi packages chained in the bundle. 
Assume bundle is MyInstaller.exe,  Msi packages are App1.msi , App2.msi and App3.msi.
I display bundle entry in Add/Remove Programs(ARP). bundle.wxs is configured such a way that individual MSI package entries are not getting displayed in ARP.

My issue is while uninstalling from Control Panel. I right click on bundle entry (say, MyInstaller) ; select Uninstall.It will open MyInstaller custom UI.  I select App1 from my Custom UI to uninstall . It successfully uninstalls App1. But I observed bundle entry, 'MyInstaller' is also getting removed from Add/Remove Programs.

My expectation is I do not want MyInstaller to be removed from ARP since other msis( App2 and App3) are not uninstalled yet. Once the last msi package is uninstalled , MyInstaller bundle entry should be removed from ARP.
Ho do I achieve this?

My bundle definition starts like

```
<Bundle Name="My Installer"         
      Version="!(bind.packageVersion.MyServerHostExe)"
      Manufacturer="xxx"
      UpgradeCode="e9707207-d9f6-92bc-43ce-aacb34e48e51"
      Condition="VersionNT &gt;= v6.0">

<RelatedBundle Id="e9707207-d9f6-92bc-43ce-aacb34e48e51" Action="Upgrade"/>
```

Comment: Ass suggested in the link I invoked Engine.Plan with parameter as LaunchAction.Modify if there are other packages installed. So bundle exe entry is not getting removed from ARP. If it is the last package getting uninstalled then I will invoke Engine.Plan with parameter as LaunchAction.Uninstall. In this case it will remove bundle exe entry from ARP. Thanks for the link and answer.

Comment: The referred link was http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17745672/how-can-i-uninstall-a-msi-but-not-the-bundle-itself-using-wix-mba